# Unable to find required project

Tags: azure-sphere

Hi I installed the SDK for azure sphere properly and as I was looking for any trail projects i got some in Github. but as explained in that I need proper template in visual studio to start a project coding. but i'm only able to access two project templates where as i can see there are 5 templates on Azure sphere. so hoping to get any reason or solution to get them.[This is what im getting as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKWOR.png)

[What im actually looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8jGK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Microsoft removed most of the Azure Sphere Templates.  As you've found there are only a couple templates left.  The strategy they are following now is to provide examples on their GitHub project here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sphere-samples

I think this approach is a good one, because they can update projects on GitHub at any time.  With the previous approach they had to wait for a SDK release to update the templates.

Comment: but to run those example projects i have to create a new project using azuresphereblink template. and add that project in it, is there any other way of running it?

Comment: To run the Microsoft GitHub Azure Sphere examples you just need to clone the entire GitHub project.  Once you have the entire tree pulled down, you can go into each sample and simply load the Visual Studio project solution file *.sln.